# Why DefaultMessageListenerContainer strongly recommends to use sessionTransacted

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Javadoc for [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html) says that

> It is strongly recommended to either set "sessionTransacted" to "true"
>   or specify an external "transactionManager".

Why is it strongly recommended? What's behind this cryptic recommendation?

Comment: Because redelivering is a lot easier with transactions than without.

Comment: I don't want re-delivery, application code takes care of this (message consumers do some interactions e.g. with non-transactional resources, so deciding if/when message should be resent/redelivered is not trivial). I believe that I've consciously chosen AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE, but that comment in javadoc suggests that there is something more to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your session is not transacted you risk message loss in the event your JVM goes down unexpectedly.

Here is the explanation of the various ack modes from AbstractMessageListenerContainer:

> The listener container offers the following message acknowledgment
>   options:

```
"sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" (default): Automatic message acknowledgment before listener execution; no redelivery in case of exception thrown.
"sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE": Automatic message acknowledgment after successful listener execution; no redelivery in case of exception thrown.
"sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE": Lazy message acknowledgment during or after listener execution; potential redelivery in case of exception thrown.
"sessionTransacted" set to "true": Transactional acknowledgment after successful listener execution; guaranteed redelivery in case of exception thrown.
```

> The exact behavior might vary according to the concrete listener
>   container and JMS provider used.

Because messaging is typically based on assured delivery, using the method that would offer the best safegaurds against message loss is recommended.  You'd have to decide for a particular use case if its worth it.

Comment: I know the delivery modes and they are described sufficiently - that's why I wonder why Spring authors are suggesting that in case of DefaultMessageListenerContainer sessionTransacted should be used. It's not like it's better than e.g. AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE (the same but better). It has different semantic and these modes are not interchangable. So the underlying quesion is - what will happen if sessionTransaced is not used besides what is in the documentation you pasted.

Comment: AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE does not account for exceptions or the JVM/thread going down.  Using AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE would tell ActiveMQ to go a head and delete any persistent messages.  So it isn't really the same, and better depends on your requirements.  Again, the recommendation is based on the fact that most people want guaranteed delivery. If your JVM, or thread goes down, you lose the message with AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE whereas if sessionTransacted is set to true, ActiveMQ will still be able to redeliver this to another consumer, or the one that went down when it comes back up.